# Problem with naming the yield return in python

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website using python and scrapy but I have issues with saving the result.

error log i receive:

```
    yield result = {
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When i remove the "**result =** ", I don't get any error but the reason I am doing that is to save the result as a variable which I use at the last part of the code in "**f.write(result)**"

The code goes below:

```
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ufcspider"

    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield result = {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').get(),
                'author': quote.css('small.author::text').get(),
                'link': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com' + quote.css("span a::attr(href)").get(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall(),
            }

        next_page = response.css("li.next a::attr(href)").get()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callable=self.parse)

        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = f'quotes-{page}.json'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(result)
        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

Comment: if your try to define result before the yield statement, then simply `yield result` should work

Comment: Do it like this `yield { 'result' : result }` and before you define `result = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define `result`, next `yield` it

```
result = { ... }

yield result
```